# How to set multiple click action in a imageview and plus, minus button increment and decrement in android

Tags: android, android-layout, onclicklistener, imagebutton, android-imagebutton

Hlw,

Problem1:
I am developing a app where I have a ImageView like favorite button where I click and change this image resource(it is done), but I want to set action when user again click this imageview and the image remain same.

Problem2:
I have two image button "plus" and "minus" I set condition to it that when user click + button middle textview increment by 1, and when it reach 10 then the button will unclickable, also for the minus button, when textviw equal=0 then it not works...
I done it by condition but when minus button reach 0 and after plus button click, it increment but not decrement it remain unclickable...
how can i solve this problem?
[Image like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p5Yva.png)

```
productWrapper.plus.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

 //           Toast.makeText(context, "Plus", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            try
            {
                String presentValStr= finalProductWrapper2.selectedQuantity.getText().toString();
                int presentIntVal=Integer.parseInt(presentValStr);
                presentIntVal++;
                if (presentIntVal>=10){
                    Toast.makeText(context,"You can select max 10 product",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    finalProductWrapper2.plus.setEnabled(false);
                }
                finalProductWrapper2.selectedQuantity.setText(String.valueOf(presentIntVal));
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(context,"Error! please try again",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
    });
        final ProductWrapper finalProductWrapper = productWrapper;
    productWrapper.heart.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finalProductWrapper.heart.setImageResource(R.drawable.heart2);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

## Point #1.

You can use boolean flag like below

```
if(flag == true){
flag = false;
// Change your Image Resource here
}
else {
flag = true;
// Do your other action 
}
```

for Minus button put following condition

```
if(YOUR_POINTS >0){
// Do your action
}
else {
// Ignore
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Pavan but it doesn't work properly.... please give me with a simple demo code...